# How to group by one axis, count elements of another one and create a new dimension with it

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following pandas dataframe `df`

```
         time  animal
0           0    cat
1           0    dog
2           1    hedgehog
3           1    cat
4           1    cat
```

I would like to

- group by time while counting how often an animal is withing the new group, like 2x cat at time 1.
- create a 2nd dimension for the count values then.

like that:

```
animal   cat  dog  hedgehog
time
  0       1    1      0
  1       2    0      1
```

Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Andrej Kesely in his answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74582359/16120011), you can use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to compute a frequency table and then, if needed, you can make a heatmap with [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) as below :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(4, 2))

sns.heatmap(pd.crosstab(df["time"], df["animal"]), annot = True)

plt.show()
```

##### # Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try `pd.crosstab`:

```py
print(pd.crosstab(df.time, df.animal))
```

Prints:

```
animal  cat  dog  hedgehog
time                      
0         1    1         0
1         2    0         1
```